# @Async annotation does not works when war is deployed on JBoss

Tags: spring, spring-boot, jboss

I have an application that contains an API Rest implemented as a Spring Boot application (1.5.18.RELEASE version)

This API contains a controller that executes a service method asynchronous. The method is marked with `@Async` annotation

The `@EnableAsync` annotation is set on my configuration class.

When i execute the application like a typical Spring Boot application, the method is executed asynchronous. if i generate a war (using maven) and this war is deployed on JBoss (6.4 Version), the same service is executed  synchronous.

Could someone explain me this behavior? Should i add any type of configuration?

The source code is below:

The Spring Boot configuration

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableCustomConfiguration
@EnableCaching
@EnableScheduling
public class WebApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(WebApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

My custom annotation:

```
@Target({ElementType.TYPE})
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Import({CustomServicesConfiguration.class})
@Documented
public @interface EnableCustomConfiguration {
}
```

My configuration class:

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan("com.bs.custom.api")
@EntityScan(basePackages = "com.bs.custom.api.domain", basePackageClasses = Jsr310JpaConverters.class)
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = "com.bs.custom.api.repository")
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(securedEnabled = true, prePostEnabled = true)
@EnableAsync
public class CustomServicesConfiguration {

    static {
        SecurityContextHolder.setStrategyName(SecurityContextHolder.MODE_INHERITABLETHREADLOCAL);
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you paste the asynchronous method?

Comment: You are using different ways to launch your application and hence a different configuration and probably no `@EnableAsync`. To build a war and be able to deploy it you should follow the steps as outlined in the [Spring Boot reference guide](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.5.18.RELEASE/reference/html/howto-traditional-deployment.html#howto-create-a-deployable-war-file).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've modified my WebApplication class to extends from SpringBootServletInitializer, as is defined on [Spring Boot reference guide](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.5.18.RELEASE/reference/html/howto-traditional-deployment.html#howto-create-a-deployable-war-file) (thanks [M.Deinum](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2696260/m-deinum))

The final WebApplication class source code is below:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableCustomConfiguration
@EnableCaching
@EnableScheduling
@EnableAsync
public class WebApplication extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(WebApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
        return application.sources(WebApplication.class);
    }   

}
```

Now, asynchronous methods run correctly on JBoss